pg_upgrade fails on pg_restore: error: connection to server at "localhost" port 5433 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
I have a PostgreSQL 13 installation on a Windows 10 server (on port 5432) that I want to migrate to a new PG 16.2 installation.
To this end, I downloaded the Windows x86-64 installer for PostgreSQL 16.2 here:    https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads
During the run of the installer I manually set up:

the default postgres user named postgres a password,
the port of the cluster to 5433,
the locale to en_US,

The PostgreSQL folder was successfully created at "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16" with everything it needs. Then it proposed to execute the  Stack Builder utility to install add-ons which I only used to install PostGIS.
To test the newly installed PostgreSQL, I added an entry in the %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf file as explained here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html
The pgpass file looks as follow:
#hostname:port:database:username:password
localhost:5432:*:postgres:************************************
localhost:5433:*:postgres:************************************

Then I successfully connected to PG with this command (it correctly fetched the password from the pgpass file):
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin\psql.exe" -d postgres://postgres@localhost:5433/postgres
psql (16.2)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT version();
                          version
------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 16.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1937, 64-bit
(1 row) 

I followed the steps as described here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html to give pg_upgrade (16) a try:

I gracefully shut down the two PG services (both 13 and 16)
Because there is no postgres user at the operating system level, I created a folder at C:\tmp with read/write access to everyone and from this folder I run the following command from a cmd.exe terminal:

"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin\pg_upgrade" -b "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin" -B "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin" -d "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data" -p 5432 -P 5433 -U postgres --check

Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                     ok
Checking database user is the install user                    ok
Checking database connection settings                         ok
Checking for prepared transactions                            ok
Checking for system-defined composite types in user tables    ok
Checking for reg* data types in user tables                   ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch         ok
Checking for incompatible "aclitem" data type in user tables  ok
Checking for user-defined encoding conversions                ok
Checking for user-defined postfix operators                   ok
Checking for incompatible polymorphic functions               ok

*Clusters are compatible*

I decided to run the exact same command again after removing the --check flag but it failed:
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                     ok
Checking database user is the install user                    ok
Checking database connection settings                         ok
Checking for prepared transactions                            ok
Checking for system-defined composite types in user tables    ok
Checking for reg* data types in user tables                   ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch         ok
Checking for incompatible "aclitem" data type in user tables  ok
Checking for user-defined encoding conversions                ok
Checking for user-defined postfix operators                   ok
Checking for incompatible polymorphic functions               ok
Creating dump of global objects                               ok
Creating dump of database schemas
                                                              ok
Checking for presence of required libraries                   ok
Checking database user is the install user                    ok
Checking for prepared transactions                            ok
Checking for new cluster tablespace directories               ok

If pg_upgrade fails after this point, you must re-initdb the
new cluster before continuing.

Performing Upgrade
------------------
Setting locale and encoding for new cluster                   ok
Analyzing all rows in the new cluster                         ok
Freezing all rows in the new cluster                          ok
Deleting files from new pg_xact                               ok
Copying old pg_xact to new server                             ok
Setting oldest XID for new cluster                            ok
Setting next transaction ID and epoch for new cluster         ok
Deleting files from new pg_multixact/offsets                  ok
Copying old pg_multixact/offsets to new server                ok
Deleting files from new pg_multixact/members                  ok
Copying old pg_multixact/members to new server                ok
Setting next multixact ID and offset for new cluster          ok
Resetting WAL archives                                        ok
Setting frozenxid and minmxid counters in new cluster         ok
Restoring global objects in the new cluster                   ok
Restoring database schemas in the new cluster
  template1
*failure*

Consult the last few lines of "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240415T170235.602/log/pg_upgrade_dump_1.log" for
the probable cause of the failure.
Failure, exiting

The mentioned pg_upgrade_dump_1.log file contains:


command: "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/bin/pg_dump" --port 5432 --username postgres --schema-only --quote-all-identifiers --binary-upgrade --format=custom  --file="C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240415T173939.552/dump/pg_upgrade_dump_1.custom" ^"dbname^=template1^" >> "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240415T173939.552/log/pg_upgrade_dump_1.log" 2>&1


command: "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/bin/pg_restore" --port 5433 --username postgres --clean --create --exit-on-error --verbose --dbname postgres "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240415T173939.552/dump/pg_upgrade_dump_1.custom" >> "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240415T173939.552/log/pg_upgrade_dump_1.log" 2>&1
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5433 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
password retrieved from file "C:\Users\<WindowsUser>\AppData\Roaming/postgresql/pgpass.conf"

I'm wondering why this automatic tool fails at this stage, because if I remove the PG 16 entry in the pgpass file, the pg_upgrade command fails much faster, which means that the pgpass file is correctly used at least for dumping the schemas, but apparently not for restoring them in the new PG 16 cluster.
Can anyone explain why exactly pg_upgrade fails and how to solve this problem? Because I really run both the PG 16 installer and the pg_upgrade tool in a vanilla way, without fancy options or setup.
which means that the PG 16 config files (such as pg_hba.conf or postgresql.conf) were not touched after the installation.
The pg_hba.conf file of PG 16 is exactly the same as the one described here.
The most relevant part being:
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
# comments (...)

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256

The PG 13 pg_hba.conf file looks like this:
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             postgres        0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

I'm therefore wondering if the issue would not be related to a different password encoding... But the documentation of the pg_upgrade tool doesn't say anything about it.

Side question:
How could I properly (i.e. ending with the same state as a fresh install) re-initialize the PG 16 cluster according to the following pg_upgade sentence: "If pg_upgrade fails after this point, you must re-initdb the new cluster before continuing." ?

Please show the pg_hba.conf file from your v16 cluster.

@LaurenzAlbe Main post edited; pg_hba.conf file added.  This is indeed the genuine file after a fresh installation of PG 16.2.

It is not obvious to me either. Perhaps name resolution problems with localhost (you could use ::1 explicitly). The easiest solution is to temporarily modigy pg_hba.conf to allow passwordless local connections.

What is the last meaningful entry in the server log file, pg_upgrade_server.log?

@jjanes the file you mentioned doesn't have any relevant information, it's all about redirecting logs to the "log" directory.
@LaurenzAlbe Could it be that the postgres password was encoded in md5 in PG 13 and that it is encoded in scram-sha-256 in PG 16 ?
Also, how could I properly re-init the PG 16 cluster according to what is written in the pg_upgrade output: If pg_upgrade fails after this point, you must re-initdb the new cluster before continuing. ?

When I provoke password problems, that is the place they show up (on linux, but I wouldn't think Windows is different here).  Maybe you have made multiple attempts, leaving multiple files in different directories, and are looking in the wrong one.  For re-init you just delete the directory where it failed, then init it again just as you did last time (only fixing the pg_hba or whatever lead to the problem if you can figure out what that is).

If the v13 server has a password hash set for the bootstrap user, then that password is transferred to the new server.  If the v13 server password hash is in md5 format but the v16 pg_hba demands scram authentication, then the upgrade will fail on the next connection attempt after the user table is transferred.
data_16_upgrade/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240418T195707.906/log/pg_upgrade_server.log:
2024-04-18 19:57:09.622 EDT [37165] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-04-18 19:57:09.622 EDT [37165] DETAIL:  User "postgres" does not have a valid SCRAM secret.
    Connection matched file "/home/jjanes/pgsql/data_16_upgrade/pg_hba.conf" line 117: "local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256"

